# Select From a Large table

Tags: sql-server, export-to-excel

I hava very large table with 1373228 rows. I need to copy the result to excel but It does not allow me to do so. Can anyone please, suggest me that how can select the table in parts and paste it  in excel. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: FIRST.... why do you want to put that many rows in an excel file?  If its for transport, use csv format, if its for querying, leave it in the server and run an sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do some export to a file using CSV for example? It should not be necessary to copy&paste. Export and import should work.

Answer (score 3):

Which Excel do you use? MS Excel 2007 has limit to **1,048,576 rows**. Previous versions - **65k limit**. Try text file.

Comment: Are you serious? Excel has a *row limit*?

Comment: Unfortunately it has. We had this problem in my company. We used CSV instead.

Comment: @voyager: that's sad. But as Zoidberg commented above: why does anybody want to have that many rows in an excel sheet in the first place?

Comment: Is it possible to use more than one sheet to work around this?

Comment: Sure. You can select first 65k rows (or 1,048,576) and then put the rest of data into others sheets. But the question "Why?" remains.

Answer (score 2):

Export it as a CSV

Comment: Just note that opening the CSV back up in Excel will chop off the data that doesn't fit within Excels row limit.